# Problem with loading getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP') in Remote action

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, remote-action

I have problem with **getHeaders** in **remote action** , its return **null** when i call remote Action through visual page .

if i call same **showIpAddress()** directly from visual page. i am able to get IP address.

why i am getting null **ipAddress** through **Remote Action**.

```
  public class ClassName {
    private static string ipAddress;
       static {       
        ipAddress = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP'); 
        }

      @RemoteAction
      public static String userDetails() { 
        showIpAddress();
       }

      public static void showIpAddress(){
       system.debug('ipAddress ' + ipAddress );
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The running user IP address is available using session management class:

```
String ip = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SourceIp');
```

Works without current page context, such as Execute Anonymous and Remote Actions.

Comment: doesn't work on public sites :(

Comment: You can use `RestContext.request.remoteAddress` if your code was invoked through a REST API.